# Google Drive Java API error when trying to upload a jpg to the drive

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to the google drive, but I am getting some errors regarding Permissions and Scopes. I followed the tutorial, the following 2 classes were copy and pasted from the java quick start, but when I run the code it gives an error which I pasted below. When I go to authenticate, it only mentions permissions for viewing, but I made sure to select all of them in the "OAuth Consent Screen". What am I missing here?

Main class:

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.ByteArrayContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.driveactivity.v2.DriveActivityScopes;
import com.google.api.services.driveactivity.v2.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.driveactivity.v2.model.File;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DriveActivityQuickstart {
    /**
     * Application name.
     */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Drive Activity API Java Quickstart";

    /**
     * Directory to store authorization tokens for this application.
     */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File("tokens");
    /**
     * Global instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * <p>If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(DriveActivityScopes.DRIVE_ACTIVITY_READONLY);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";
    /**
     * Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}.
     */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;
    /**
     * Global instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = DriveActivityQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        Credential credential =
                new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver())
                        .authorize("user");
        System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());

        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive Activity client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized DriveActivity client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static com.google.api.services.driveactivity.v2.DriveActivity getDriveActivityService()
            throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        com.google.api.services.driveactivity.v2.DriveActivity service =
                new com.google.api.services.driveactivity.v2.DriveActivity.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                        .build();
        return service;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        com.google.api.services.driveactivity.v2.DriveActivity service = getDriveActivityService();

        // Print the recent activity in your Google Drive.
        QueryDriveActivityResponse result =
                service.activity().query(new QueryDriveActivityRequest().setPageSize(10)).execute();
        List<DriveActivity> activities = result.getActivities();
        if (activities == null || activities.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No activity.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recent activity:");
            for (DriveActivity activity : activities) {
                String time = getTimeInfo(activity);
                String action = getActionInfo(activity.getPrimaryActionDetail());
                List<String> actors =
                        activity.getActors().stream()
                                .map(DriveActivityQuickstart::getActorInfo)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                List<String> targets =
                        activity.getTargets().stream()
                                .map(DriveActivityQuickstart::getTargetInfo)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                System.out.printf(
                        "%s: %s, %s, %s\n", time, truncated(actors), action, truncated(targets));
            }
        }

        UploadBasic.uploadBasic();

    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the first elements in a list.
     */
    private static String truncated(List<String> array) {
        return truncatedTo(array, 2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the first elements in a list.
     */
    private static String truncatedTo(List<String> array, int limit) {
        String contents = array.stream().limit(limit).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        String more = array.size() > limit ? ", ..." : "";
        return "[" + contents + more + "]";
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of a set property in an object, or else "unknown".
     */
    private static <T> String getOneOf(AbstractMap<String, T> obj) {
        Iterator<String> iterator = obj.keySet().iterator();
        return iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : "unknown";
    }

    /**
     * Returns a time associated with an activity.
     */
    private static String getTimeInfo(DriveActivity activity) {
        if (activity.getTimestamp() != null) {
            return activity.getTimestamp();
        }
        if (activity.getTimeRange() != null) {
            return activity.getTimeRange().getEndTime();
        }
        return "unknown";
    }

    /**
     * Returns the type of action.
     */
    private static String getActionInfo(ActionDetail actionDetail) {
        return getOneOf(actionDetail);
    }

    /**
     * Returns user information, or the type of user if not a known user.
     */
    private static String getUserInfo(User user) {
        if (user.getKnownUser() != null) {
            KnownUser knownUser = user.getKnownUser();
            Boolean isMe = knownUser.getIsCurrentUser();
            return (isMe != null && isMe) ? "people/me" : knownUser.getPersonName();
        }
        return getOneOf(user);
    }

    /**
     * Returns actor information, or the type of actor if not a user.
     */
    private static String getActorInfo(Actor actor) {
        if (actor.getUser() != null) {
            return getUserInfo(actor.getUser());
        }
        return getOneOf(actor);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the type of a target and an associated title.
     */
    private static String getTargetInfo(Target target) {
        if (target.getDriveItem() != null) {
            return "driveItem:\"" + target.getDriveItem().getTitle() + "\"";
        }
        if (target.getDrive() != null) {
            return "drive:\"" + target.getDrive().getTitle() + "\"";
        }
        if (target.getFileComment() != null) {
            DriveItem parent = target.getFileComment().getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                return "fileComment:\"" + parent.getTitle() + "\"";
            }
            return "fileComment:unknown";
        }
        return getOneOf(target);
    }
}
```

Uploading class:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

/* Class to demonstrate use of Drive insert file API */
public class UploadBasic {

    /**
     * Upload new file.
     *
     * @return Inserted file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
     * @throws IOException if service account credentials file not found.
     */
    public static String uploadBasic() throws IOException {
        // Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
        // TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity for
        // guides on implementing OAuth2 for your application.
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
                .createScoped(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(
                credentials);

        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                requestInitializer)
                .setApplicationName("Drive samples")
                .build();
        // Upload file photo.jpg on drive.
        File fileMetadata = new File();
//        fileMetadata.set("photo.jpg", null);
        fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
        // File's content.
        java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
        // Specify media type and file-path for file.
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
        try {
            System.out.println("TESTING THIS LINE");
            File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                    .setFields("id")
                    .execute();
            System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
            return file.getId();
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
            System.err.println("Unable to upload file: " + e.getDetails());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

error:

```
    > Task :run FAILED
Credentials saved to C:\java\Quickstart\tokens
Recent activity:
2023-03-15T02:55:06.045Z: [people/me], edit, [driveItem:"count.txt"]
2023-03-15T02:53:57.041Z: [people/me], edit, [driveItem:"count.txt"]
2023-03-15T02:50:31.803Z: [people/me], edit, [driveItem:"count.txt"]
2023-03-15T02:50:12.453Z: [people/me], create, [driveItem:"count.txt"]
2023-03-15T02:49:55.521Z: [people/me], delete, [driveItem:"Untitled document"]
2023-03-15T02:48:32.831Z: [people/me], edit, [driveItem:"Untitled document"]
2023-03-15T02:48:32.513Z: [people/me], create, [driveItem:"Untitled document"]
TESTING THIS LINE
Unable to upload file: {"code":403,"details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","reason":"ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT","domain":"googleapis.com","metadata":{"method":"google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.Create","se
rvice":"drive.googleapis.com"}}],"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Insufficient Permission","reason":"insufficientPermissions"}],"message":"Request had insufficient authentication scopes.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&uploadType=resumable
{
  "code": 403,
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
      "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
      "domain": "googleapis.com",
      "metadata": {
        "method": "google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.Create",
        "service": "drive.googleapis.com"
      }
    }
  ],
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Insufficient Permission",
      "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:570)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:493)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:603)
        at UploadBasic.uploadBasic(UploadBasic.java:51)
        at DriveActivityQuickstart.main(DriveActivityQuickstart.java:143)
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to change the scopes in your code. It seems that the quickstart that you got was originally for Drive Activity because it's requesting the scope `DriveActivityScopes.DRIVE_ACTIVITY_READONLY`. This only allows you to read Drive Activity information and nothing else. Since you changed the code to upload a file you have to change or add the necessary scope.

You can usually find the required scopes in the page of each API. To upload an image with [`files.create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) you can use one of the following scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`

The `drive` scope allows you wider access, while `drive.file` only allows you to access the files that your app created. As a rule, you should only use the scopes you need for a specific action and avoid getting full access if you don't need it.

You can find the equivalent for Java in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/DriveScopes.html). All this explanation boils down to changing this line:

```
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(DriveActivityScopes.DRIVE_ACTIVITY_READONLY);
```

To this:

```
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
```

Or this:

```
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
```

Comment: So I deleted the StoredCredential file and re-authenticated and this helped change the scope in the consent screen, however I still get the same permissions error as before. I changed it to this

private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);

Comment: That's odd, make sure you've deleted the token file within your `DATA_STORE_DIR". You could also try the more general `DriveScopes.Drive` scope as a test to see if you actually need more access. Also make sure that the Drive API is enabled in your GCP project. After you generate the access token you can also plug it into the `tokeninfo` endpoint to check its scopes. Try with: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=accessToken`.

Comment: I did delete the token file and re-generated it. I also tried the DriveScopes.Drive. Same error. The Drive API is enabled in my google cloud project. I am not sure how to open the "StoredCredential" file that got generated after I consented the app because it is obfuscated if I open it in notepad.